# activeform variable not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery function to activate and deactivate forms based off the current form. When I click on the submit button I can get the value of the activeform on the page load if I have it set to ID, but nothing off the second form. When I set it to class it doesn't seem to load any at all and I get no alert back when I click the submit. My jquery is as such:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeform = "register";
    $("#loginlink").click(function(e) {
        var activeform = "login";
        $("#login").show("blind", 1000);
        $("#register").hide("blind", 1000);
    })
        $("#registerlink").click(function(e) {
        var activeform = "register";
        $("#register").show("blind", 1000);
        $("#login").hide("blind", 1000);
    })
        $(".submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            alert(activeform);
    });
});
</script>
```

And the code for my forms:

```
<p>
<form id="register">

        <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label for username><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Username</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label for password><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label for email><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="email"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" title="You may be notified of delayed or denied payments." data-toggle="tooltip"></i></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label for submit><i class="fa fa-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="By Registering you Agree to be Bound by our Terms of Service"></i></label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success form-control" class="submit">Register</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        </div>

</form>
        <form id="login" style="display:none;">

        <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label for username><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Username</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label for password><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success form-control" class="submit">Login</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        </div>

</form>
</p>
```

Login | Register
Last but not least. Here's a fiddle. :)
https://jsfiddle.net/rm6j5da9/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were recreating the `activeform` variable every time in the click event. remove the `var` keyword. **you already declared that as a global variable** inside the document ready scope.

```
$(function(){
  var activeform = "register";

  $("#loginlink").click(function(e) {
     activeform = "login";
     $("#login").show("blind", 1000);
     $("#register").hide("blind", 1000);
  });

  $("#registerlink").click(function(e) {
     activeform = "register";
     $("#register").show("blind", 1000);
     $("#login").hide("blind", 1000);
  });

  $(".submit").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert(activeform);
  });

});
```

Also you need to make sure that you have the submit css class on both the **login** and **register** buttons

[Here](http://jsbin.com/veresukudu/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample

Comment: I was able to do it with a combination of your solution, plus my own. Essentially by utilizing ID to call it instead of class and then simply updating the text on the button depending on the form that was current. Thank you. :)